# Longitudinal dielectric wave does it exist in charge free region?

Tags: electromagnetism

can we transmit energy through Longitudinal dielectric wave when the surrounding is charge free. Please give me a good link about L.M.D. I a beginner about this topic.

Comment: Electromagnetic waves are always transversal. One can transmit acoustic energy trough dielectrics. That's what a piezo transformer does: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt107/slyt107.pdf

Comment: That means there is no such wave like Longitudinal dielectric?! @CuriousOne

Comment: It means that I have taken a shot at two interpretations of what you could have meant by "longitudinal dielectric wave". If you meant some form of longitudinal electromagnetic wave, no, that doesn't exist, even though I imagine that some Teslaites and many Overunitites believe in them religiously.